# Access Validation Rule Violations on Append Query

Tags: ms-access

I'm recieving the following error on trying to run an append query in access.

Microsoft Office Access set .... and it didnt't add... 779280 records(s) due to validation rule violations.

If I choose to run the query anyways, nothing actually happens.

To give some context, I'm simply trying to copy a populated field, consisting of values similar to "16-2009-02, 34-2010-02, et cetera" to another currently unpopulated field.

The fields themselves have no set validation rules, and both have the standard text field options.

I'm hoping to be able to simply remove those hyphens, and fix the issue.  But I guess that's what I'm not sure about, are those hyphens actually a problem?

Running SP3 w/ Access 2003.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the destination field have Allow Zero Length set to false or Required set to true? If it does, it is possible that some of the data from the source column is null or is set to an empty string. In addition, you should verify that the field sizes on the new column is equal to larger than the source column.

**EDIT** On appending from one table to another, you must ensure that you populate the columns that makeup the primary key of the destination table. Thus, from your screenshot, you need to include the `loggerid` and `datetime` columns from the "Log ID" table. Now, if there are collisions, Access should tell you how many rows generated collisions and let you append the ones that did not collide with the uniqueness restriction on `loggerid` and `datetime`

Comment: Allow Zero Length = Yes
Required = No

I do have some Null fields, but I would think that rather applying to the entire query, it would only fail for those that do.

Currently, the whole query is failing.

Comment: And the field size on the destination query is greater than or equal to the field size of the source?

Comment: BTW, does the destination table have an AutoNumber column? I take it that you are excluding this column from your Append query.

Comment: No, the destination field doesn't have an AutoNumber Column.  

As far as the General Properties go, here they are:

Field Size = 50
Format = Null
Input Mask = Null
Caption = Null
...  = Null
Validation Text= Null
Required= No
Allow Zero Length = Yes
Indexed = No
Compression = Yes
IME Mode = No Control
IME Sentence Mode = No
Smart Tags = No

Furthermore, I went and deleted all fields that I'm trying to copy that had Null values, but am still getting the same error.

It's bizarre.

Comment: Does the destination table have a primary key? If so, how are you populating that column when you append your records?

Comment: I've attached some screenshots here:
http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/5421/mainle.jpg
http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/4562/query.jpg

The primary key is a combination of the Loggerid and Date/Time.  We use temperature loggers that monitor stream temp every 30min...

Comment: The column I want to populate is the EffortID btw.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the screenshot. On your append, you need to append records into the PK of the destination table (and any other Required fields) and those new values must be unique across the whole table. Thus, you need to include the columns loggerid and datetime persuming that the source values you are appending will not create collisions.

Comment: So, what that entails is simplying adding the Loggerid/Datetime fields into the query if I understood that correctly?

Comment: Yes. Now, if the loggerid and datetime in the source table already exist in the destination table, then you will get collision alerts again.

Comment: That data does exist in the destination table.

I'm thinking that I'm using the wrong sort of query here.  Should I instead be using an update query?  If you look at the images I posted, I simply want to add those effortid's on the left to the table on the right.

Comment: Correct. If you wish to simply update the matching values, then an Update query is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the target column is not indexed or, if it is, that duplicates are allowed.  Access often makes indexing decisions on your behalf and sometimes they are not correct.